# Monomorphisms into injective abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Assume we are given a monomorphism of abelian groups
$$
f:H\longrightarrow G
$$
and $G$ is injective, that is, divisible in this category.

Is it true that $G/f(H)$ is divisible (and injective therefore)?

Comment: First, I think you may have meant $\;f(H)\;$ , not $\;H\;$ , which could be completely unrelated to $\;G\;$ . Second, **any** subgroup of an abelian group is normal...And yes: quotient group of divisible groups are divisible.

Answer (score 0):

The following conditions are equivalent for a ring $R$:

1. every right ideal of $R$ is projective (as right $R$-module);
2. every submodule of a projective right $R$-module is projective;
3. every quotient of an injective right $R$-module is injective.

When these conditions are satisfied the ring is called *right hereditary*.

Clearly $\mathbb{Z}$ is hereditary because of condition 1. But condition 3 is also easy to verify, because injective is the same as divisible and quotients of divisible groups are divisible.